# image upload in django

Tags: python, django

Could someone point me towards an example on image uploading in django. I have tried the documentation and the djangobook, but all I found were examples with file uploads. I am new to Django and I would like to first try to see how an example works before writing my own form. Thanks a lot.

Comment: What are looking for exactly? In the end, an image upload is the same as uploading any other file. Are you trying to do some postprocessing on the images like thumbnailing?

Comment: I would like to save the image on disk or process it directly from the memory

Answer (score 1):

You can check out these links. just see this meets your requirements.
[Using ajax and django](http://embrangler.com/2010/08/ajax-uploads-images-in-django/)

[Django Photologue](http://code.google.com/p/django-photologue/)

Answer (score 1):

Maybe this will help a little:

forms.py

```
class SomeForm(forms.Form):
    picture = forms.ImageField(required=False)
```

views.py

```
if request.method == 'POST':
    form = SomeForm(request.POST, request.FILES)
    if form.is_valid():
        dest_file = open('some_image_file.jpg', 'wb+')
        for chunk in  request.FILES['picture_field'].chunks():
            dest_file.write(chunk)
        dest_file.close()
```

I haven't ran this peace of code, could be that I miss something... But in general it is like this and the file will be saved to the disk (by default chunks should be 2.5 megs). Just remember that in template where is your form, form must have enctype="multipart/form-data".

When you have file savedm you can use PIL to resize, add watermarks and everything you like to edit image ;)

Good luck.
Ignas

Answer (score 0):

It is a bit outdated but still works with django 1.3

http://www.carcosa.net/jason/software/django/stockphoto/

Comment: Maybe I should not say outdated, just does not get worked on much anymore.